# How to get elevation in point using dted tif file offline in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, tiff, arcgis-runtime

I'm trying to get elevation in specific points from a local file that has dted tif file format.
Using Esri.ArcGISRuntime library I get the error - "Null pointer: Elevation must be loaded before you can get elevation". Maybe someone has tips - is this possible using Esri.ArcGISRuntime? Or maybe there are other libraries that could help? Below code snippet:

'''

```
        //parentFolder - folder with dted.tif file 
        List<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(parentFolder, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

        var surface = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Surface();
        RasterElevationSource rasterElevationSource = new RasterElevationSource(files);

        surface.ElevationSources.Add(rasterElevationSource);
        surface.LoadAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        //lat, lon - some random coordinates
        var mp = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Geometry.MapPoint(lat, lon);           
        var res = surface.GetElevationAsync(mp).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine($"Elevation: {res}");
```

'''

Comment: Have you done an internet search for that error? Without much effort, I get https://community.esri.com/t5/net-maps-sdk-questions/elevation-not-loaded-profile-job/td-p/1161090 and https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/help/mapping/map-authoring/basemap-and-elevation-layers.htm. It does  not seem to be an uncommon issue

Comment: On a side note please don’t use GetResult. That can lead to deadlocks. Write correct async code with the await keyword

Comment: @Flydog57, thanks for the point, but both of the link didn't help, will continue to dig more

Comment: @dotMorten This is sample code to have a working approach - I will refactor it, of course.

Comment: Manage to resolve current exception by adding - await rasterElevationSource.LoadAsync(); Next exception - null pointer: spatial reference must be provided

Comment: You never specified a spatial reference for mp.